# How to allow web hosting in EC2 with Linux AMI (port 80 rule added)

Tags: web, amazon-ec2, hosting, ec2-api-tools

I've added rules for port 80 for http and even 443 for https but the url returns this site can't be reached. Do I need to configure the firewall somehow?

Also for url I used the public DNS address, I also tried the domain returned by host [public ip] command. Both didn't allow access.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Did you install a web server on the instance? (There is no web server by default.) From the instance command-line, if you run `curl localhost`, what comes back?

Comment: No sir I did not. I'll try to setup an apache. And I will try that command once I get home. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to add http rule in the default group in security group.